# Reactjs: Cannot read property 'myProp' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Kind Attention: Newbie here**. The question might seem trivial, but it is seemingly difficult for me.

I was modifying the [Reactjs Tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html), where I am stuck in a very trivial problem.

```
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square"> {props.value} </button>
  );
}

class Board extends React.Component {

  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="status">{this.props.printStatus()}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default class Game extends React.Component {

// COnstructor
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    myProp: 'Hi'
  }
}

// Gets gameplay status
getStatus() {
  return this.state.myProp;  // error coming here
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board printStatus={this.getStatus}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am getting error at this line `TypeError: Cannot read property 'myProp' of undefined`:

[image]

This means the property `myProp` inside `state` of component `Game` is not accessible or not being read.
**What could be the issue?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because passing `this.getStatus` directly to child component will lose its caller (this). Instead, you can pass a 'wrapped version' of it.

This closure will preserve caller of `getStatus`, thus return correct value.

```js
function Square(props) {
  return (
    <button className="square"> {props.value} </button>
  );
}

class Board extends React.Component {

  renderSquare(i) {
    return <Square />;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="status">{this.props.printStatus()}</div>
    );
  }
}

class Game extends React.Component {

// COnstructor
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    myProp: 'Hi'
  }
}

// Gets gameplay status
getStatus() {

  return this.state.myProp;
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="game">
        <div className="game-board">
          <Board printStatus={() =>  this.getStatus()}/>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
    <Game />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<div id="root">
     
</div>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's for the answer with correct reason. It was the reason, I was looking for, to build my foundation.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind `this` to the `getStatus` function in your `constructor`.

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    myProp: 'Hi'
  };
  this.getStatus = this.getStatus.bind(this);
}
```

https://gist.github.com/fongandrew/f28245920a41788e084d77877e65f22f

Answer (score 0):

Or you can just define getStatus as an arrow function:

```
getStatus = () => this.state.myProp
```

Check this out: https://medium.com/byte-sized-react/what-is-this-in-react-25c62c31480